# i3wm - open multiwindows program on specific workspace

Tags: i3

I have it so that when I start i3mw it opens me certain programs like such:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 4; exec /snap/bin/slack'
```

However this does not work for applications that have multiple windows that I'd like to have on separate workspaces. For example I when opening Firefox I get two windows, but I'd like to have them on say workspace 1 and 2. How can I achieve that?